# How to create a central repo in TortoiseHg without it showing up in the Repository Registry?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I set up a local repo in TortoiseHg and can see the folder in the Repository Registry list.  I want to create a central repository that I can push to and pull from when I'm on different computers.  I have a Microsoft OneDrive account so I thought I would use that.  I did File>Clone Repository... and browsed to OneDrive where I had created a "Mercurial" folder.  It apparently did clone the repo since now I see a second repo in the list by the same name but in Bold letters.

I really didn't want to see the central repo in the list.  That is only going to cause confusion.  At work, we use BitBucket for our central repo and that doesn't show up in the list, so why does the OneDrive repo?  Any way to hide it?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out so I gave up and created my own BitBucket account, which I didn't realize was free.  It works as expected using BitBucket.

Comment: I've since noticed that OneDrive wasn't syncing so now I'm wondering if that was the real problem.

Comment: The THG repository "registry" really has very little to do with how Mercurial actually works. Its just THG's way of remembering where repositories are. Mercurial itself doesn't know about it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the entry in the Repository Registry and select "Remove from Registry".

Comment: When I do that then it removes it but then when I push it says "repository does not exist"

Comment: @user3217883 When you clone a repository, the clone points back to the original, not the other way around.  Clone the "central" repository back to your local system and the new clone will default push to back to "central".  You can also select your existing local repo and go View, Synchonize and set the default push location to your new "central" repository.

Comment: @user3217883 You can also directly edit/create the `.hg\hgrc` file in the repo and set the default.  Find (or create) the `[paths]` section and set `default = C:\OneDrive\YourRepo` or whatever the correct path is to the central repository.